# Bin arbitrary data using canonical ordering

Tags: list-manipulation, histograms, sorting, counting

I have two lists of words, `nouns` and `verbs`:

```
nouns = RandomWord["Noun", 10] // Sort
(* {"concrete", "curdling", "decoupage", "fairy", "hairline", "hick", "orchid", "referral", "sleepwear", "snorkel"} *)

verbs = RandomWord["Verb", 100];
```

and I want to know how many elements of `verbs` come between each successive pair of `nouns` in alphabetical order. In other words, I want to construct a histogram, treating the elements of `nouns` as the boundaries of the bins.

If instead I had two lists of numbers, `integers` and `reals`, I could do this as follows:

```
integers = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 10] // Sort;    
reals = RandomReal[{1, 100}, 100];

BinCounts[reals, {integers}]
(* {17, 0, 15, 1, 1, 11, 2, 25, 11} *)
```

But this does not work with the words: `BinCounts` (and `Histogram` and related functions) will only accept a set of bin boundaries that are real numbers.

The best I can think of is

```
Function[v, SelectFirst[nouns, OrderedQ[{v, #}] &]] /@ verbs
```

but this seems very inefficient. Is there a way to use `BinCounts` to do this, or a more efficient (natural / neat) way to do it otherwise?

---

To clarify what I actually want to use this for, in case it's helpful: there is a (large) ordered set $\mathfrak{S}$ of elements (all words) and I have generated a subset $\mathfrak{T}$ (`nouns`) whose elements are (I believe) approximately uniformly sampled from $\mathfrak{S}$. To test this, I have generated a new sample $\mathfrak{U}$ (`verbs`) and want to plot a histogram of $\mathfrak{U}$, using $\mathfrak{T}$ as the bin boundaries.

Comment: `binlists=DeleteCases[SplitBy[Sort[Join[nouns,verbs]], MemberQ[nouns,#]&] , {__?(MemberQ[nouns,#]&)}]` and `bincounts = Length/@binlists`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
ordering = Ordering[Join[nouns, verbs]];
DeleteCases[
 Total[
  Split[
   Join[
     ConstantArray[0, Length[nouns]], 
     ConstantArray[1, Length[verbs]]
     ][[ordering]]
   ], 
  {2}],
 0
 ]
```

does what you want?

An alternate way of writing it is

```
(DeleteCases[#, 0] &)@(Total[#, {2}] &)@Split@Join[
     ConstantArray[0, Length[nouns]],
     ConstantArray[1, Length[verbs]]
     ][[ordering]]
```

The key part here is

```
Join[
 ConstantArray[0, Length[nouns]], 
 ConstantArray[1, Length[verbs]]
 ][[ordering]]
```

The output is a list of zeros and ones where each zero stands for a noun  and each one stands for a verb in the ordered list `Sort[Join[nouns,verbs]]`. `Split` helps us to find runs of the same element and we can employ `Total[#,{2}]&` to count the ones in each run. In the end, we remove the "nouns" with `DeleteCases[#,0]&`.

Comment: Thanks. I am now using `Length /@ Cases[Join[Map[{False, #} &, nouns], Map[{True, #} &, verbs]] // SortBy[Last] // SplitBy[#, First] &, {{True, _} ..}]`, which is essentially the technique in your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that with `nouns = RandomWord["Noun", 100000] // Sort;
verbs = RandomWord["Verb", 1000000];`, your method needs `4.41` seconds on my machine while mine needs `0.649584`. I don't know how large your lists really are...

Answer (score 2):

Why not just transforming the word into a number?
This assumes all lowercase, English words with characters in `CharacterRange["a", "z"]` and of up to 23 characters (`Max[StringLength@DictionaryLookup["*"]]`)

```
Word2Number[word_String] := 
 FromDigits[PadRight[ToCharacterCode[word] - 96, 26], 23]

BinCounts[Word2Number@verbs, {Sort@Word2Number@nouns}]
(* {0, 1, 11, 17, 4, 7, 7, 8, 0} *)
```

Comment: @StephenPowell Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks. This does indeed answer the question as posed. I have accepted Henrik's answer because it is somewhat more general. This answer works in any case where one can define a "hash" function (`Word2Number`) that preserves the order used by `Sort`.